# Javascript Number To True/False

Tags: javascript, if-statement, constructor

Can anyone help me with my code? I wanna make `isItHigher` to true if my number is higher than 200. What I'm getting to console is a number, not a boolean. Any ideas why?

```js
class Example {
    constructor(title, author, amount) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.books = +amount
        isItHigher(this.books);
    }
}

const exampleCall = new Example("Example Book", "Example Author", 300);
console.log('exampleCall --->', exampleCall);


function isItHigher(amount) {
    if (amount > 200) {
        return true
    }
    if (amount < 100000000) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `isItHigher(this.books)`, but you don't do anything with the value that is returned.

Comment: Incidentally, `if (amount < 100000000)` is redundant; anything greater than 200 will already have returned true based on the first conditional.  That whole function could be reduced to `return amount > 200`

Comment: And for the truly economical, further golfed to `isItHigher = (amount) => amount > 200`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Example {
    constructor(title, author, amount) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.books = +amount
        this.isHigher = isItHigher(this.books);
    }
}

const exampleCall = new Example("Example Book", "Example Author", 300);
console.log('exampleCall --->', exampleCall);


function isItHigher(amount) {
    if (amount > 200) {
        return true
    }
    if (amount < 100000000) {
        return false
    }
}
```

The function `isItHigher` is returning the boolean correctly but the returned value is not assigned to anything. You need to assign the returned value of the function `isItHigher` into a variable `this.isHigher` for example.

Answer (score 0):

you are not assiging the 'isItHigher' function to anything, therefore you will not see it when you log the value of 'exampleCall' out.
You will need to assign it like this in the constructor().

this.higher = isItHigher(this.books);

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do exactly, but if you want your books value to be a boolean value, you should transfer the value that comes as a result of your control to books.

```
class Example {
    constructor(title, author, amount) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.books= isItHigher(amount);
    }
}

const exampleCall = new Example("Example Book", "Example Author", 300);
console.log('exampleCall --->', exampleCall);


function isItHigher(amount) {
    if (amount > 200) {
        return true
    }
    if (amount < 100000000) {
        return false
    }
}
```